# Java binding instance using other instance using Guice

Tags: java, binding, guice

there is a configuration file that I want to bind using Guice but the problem is I get that file using my manager class and I don't have an instance of it. To make clear, I explain on code:

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ConfigManager.class).to(SimpleConfigManager.class).asEagerSingleton(); // My manager
        
        bind(PropertiesConfiguration.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("versionConfig")).toInstance(configManager.getResourceConfig("version.properties"));
                                                                                                   // ^ I need an instance of SimpleConfigManager here
    }
}
```

So, how can I create/get an instance without using the "new" keyword?

Comment: why don't you just make the getResourceConfig("version.properties") as static?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called [ProvidesMethod](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods).

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ConfigManager.class).to(SimpleConfigManager.class).asEagerSingleton(); 
        
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("versionConfig")
    public PropertiesConfiguration providePropertiesConfiguration(ConfigManager configManager) {
        return configManager.getResourceConfig("version.properties");
    }
}
```